# Factory helper not working within PHPUnit setup method

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Writing some unit tests, and I want to have an object created before the tests in the class are done. So I set up the `setUpBeforeClass()` method:

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Unit;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Location;
class UserTests extends TestCase {
    const FAKEID = 9999999;
    public static function setUpBeforeClass() : void {
        parent::setUpBeforeClass();
        factory(Location::class)->make(["id" => self::FAKEID])->save();
    }
}
```

But when I try running this, I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Location].
```

But the factory class is set up properly. In fact, if I move this same line down to one of my test functions it works perfectly.

```
public function testCreateUser() {
    factory(Location::class)->make(["id" => self::FAKEID])->save();
    // do other stuff...
}
```

The only thing that sticks out to me as different about `setUpBeforeClass()` is that it's a static method, but I don't know why that would prevent the factory class from working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel does a lot of setting up in the `setUp()` method in the `TestCase` class. The `setUpBeforeClass()` method is called before that, that's why your factory is not loaded yet.

The Laravel's `TestCase` class `setup` method ([see class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php)):

```
/**
 * Setup the test environment.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function setUp()
{
    if (! $this->app) {
        $this->refreshApplication();
    }

    $this->setUpTraits();

    foreach ($this->afterApplicationCreatedCallbacks as $callback) {
        call_user_func($callback);
    }

    Facade::clearResolvedInstances();
    Model::setEventDispatcher($this->app['events']);

    $this->setUpHasRun = true;
}
```

Change your code to use `setUp` instead:

```
protected static function setUp() : void 
{
    parent::setUp();

    factory( Location::class )->make( ["id" => self::FAKEID] )->save();
}
```

Comment: But this method is run before every test. Seems a waste to have to create and insert new records before every test, and remove them after every test.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but that's what you get when marrying a framework.. Laravel is already doing it before every test.. You want to use factories based on Laravel, so you need Laravel when it's setup and running, and that's after the TestCase `setUp` fixture is called..

Comment: Btw, you always should reset the state at the start of every test. Basing tests on previous test states is a no no in unit testing. That's why Laravel also resets itself every test.

Comment: Well what I’m doing is just inserting some records that are needed by foreign keys on the records that I’m actually testing. Like in the example I used I need a location set up before I can create a user. I expect I’ll go with this answer, just seems like unnecessary DB access, over dozens of tests.

Comment: Why doesn't this work in a dataProvider either?  There a way around that?